# React - useEffect block loading page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I started learning React few days ago, and now, i'm stuck with a useEffect problem.

To put you in the context, i'm building a single planets page, and you can switch between planets and display their informations.

We have to click on some buttons to get some details on the planet. So, when buttons are selected, they get a certain class. So, I want these buttons to get back their default className when we go to another planet !

So I've wrote a useEffect that edit classNames of some buttons each time we switch between planets, by clicking in planets buttons.

But after that, if I reload the page from the reload button of Google, my components don't render at all, I only get the background of my app.

```
useEffect(() => {
  buttonOverview.className = planetDetails[selectedPlanet].name;
  buttonStructure.className = "buttonStructure";
  buttonSurface.className = "buttonSurface";
}, [selectedPlanet]);
```

There is the error code from google : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'className')"

But I don't understand, because i've learned that useEffect is played only after the rendering, so what's the problem ?

Comment: You shouldn't be manipulating the DOM like that in React. You should be [setting new state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) with that information, and allow the JSX in your render using that updated state.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to `useEffect` here. Store the selected planet in state, and then use CSS to update the classes.

Here's an example (planets not to scale).

```js
const { useState } = React;

// Passing in an array of planets
function Example({ planets }) {

  // Initialise the state
  const [ selected, setSelected ] = useState('');

  // Update the state with the planet's name
  // from its dataset
  function handleSelected(e) {
    setSelected(e.target.dataset.name);
  }

  // For each planet create a new Planet component
  // passing in the name, the current selected state
  // and the handler that updates the state
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="planets">
        {planets.map(planet => {
          return (
            <Planet
              name={planet}
              selected={selected}
              handleSelected={handleSelected}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
      {selected && (
        <div className="info">I am&nbsp;
          <span class="bold">{selected}</span>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );

}

function Planet(props) {

  // Get the name, current state of `selected`,
  // and the handler from the component props
  const { name, selected, handleSelected } = props;

  // Work out whether it's selected or not
  const isSelected = name === selected ? 'selected' : '';

  // Create a new React className using that information
  const cls = [ 'planet', name, isSelected ].join(' ');

  return (
    <div
      data-name={name}
      className={cls}
      onClick={handleSelected}
    ></div>
  );

}

const planets = ['mercury', 'venus', 'earth', 'mars', 'jupiter', 'saturn', 'uranus', 'neptune', 'pluto'];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example planets={planets} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
.planets { display: flex; flex-direction: row; }
.planet { border: 2px solid white; border-radius: 50%; }
.planet:hover { cursor: pointer; }
.mercury { background-image: url(https://dummyimage.com/20x20/ff0000/0011ff&text=Mercury); width:20px; height: 20px; }
.venus { background-image: url(https://dummyimage.com/40x40/bda6a6/0011ff&text=Venus); width:40px; height: 40px; }
.earth { background-image: url(https://dummyimage.com/70x70/387d70/fff&text=Earth); width:70px; height: 70px; }
.mars { background-image: url(https://dummyimage.com/40x40/913535/fff&text=Mars); width:40px; height: 40px; }
.jupiter { background-image: url(https://dummyimage.com/150x150/ab823f/fff&text=Jupiter); width:150px; height: 150px; }
.saturn { background-image: url(https://dummyimage.com/95x95/b8ab97/fff&text=Saturn); width:95px; height: 95px; }
.uranus { background-image: url(https://dummyimage.com/50x50/8f5300/fff&text=Uranus); width:50px; height: 50px; }
.neptune { background-image: url(https://dummyimage.com/40x40/66a693/fff&text=Neptune); width:40px; height: 40px; }
.pluto { background-image: url(https://dummyimage.com/20x20/a5bdb6/fff&text=Pluto); width:20px; height: 20px; }
.selected { border: 2px solid black; }
.info { margin-top: 1em; }
.bold { font-weight: 600; text-transform: uppercase; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of React state to store and set those class names. You can do this by making use of the `useState` hook.

**Scenario 1:**

This should do the trick:

```
const [buttonOverviewClassName, setButtonOverviewClassName] = useState("");
const [buttonStructureClassName, setButtonStructureClassName] = useState("");
const [buttonSurfaceClassName, setButtonSurfaceClassName] = useState("");

useEffect(() => {
  setButtonOverviewClassName(planetDetails[selectedPlanet].name);
  setButtonStructureClassName("buttonStructure");
  setButtonSurfaceClassName("buttonSurface");
}, [selectedPlanet]);
```

Then for a `button` in your `return` statement you could just set the `className` to match that value like this:

```
<button className={buttonOverviewClassName}>Overview</button>
```

**Scenario 2:**

Another option is to group all the classNames together as one object since you're changing them all together anyway.

You can do this:

```
const [classNames, setClassNames] = useState({
  overview: "",
  structure: "",
  surface: "",
});

useEffect(() => {
  setClassNames({
    overview: planetDetails[selectedPlanet].name,
    structure: "buttonStructure",
    surface: "buttonSurface"
  });
}, [selectedPlanet])
```

Then use that like this:

```
<button className={classNames.overview}>Overview</button>
```

Comment: Wow, you teached me so much with your answer ! Really thx man ! Nonetheless, it doesn't totally help me. I mean, now, my page can fully render, but I return to my older problem, i need my button to have their default class back when changing planets, and this is not the solution (i really don't know if i gave you enought informations), but you definitely helped me to better understand useEffect, so thank you !

Comment: I'll update my answer to cater for defaults as well :P

Comment: Right yeah actually now that I think of it I'll need more info, but I'll make an edit which might point you in the right direction.

Comment: @remsB nevermind, I believe the answer that provided is a better solution for your specific scenario.